# Unable to populate listbox

Tags: c#, bluetooth, listbox

Im having a bit of trouble with displaying a list in my listbox.
When I had everything in one class, things seemed to work fine but I cant figure out why it doesnt work now. My app, when clicked on the scan button, goes to a different class where there is a new thread created to scan for available bluetooth devices and the a list with those devices is created. Once the list is passed back to a method in Form1 class, it doesnt update the listbox. In debugging mode I could see that there are items on the list but nothing appears in the listbox. The listbox displays items if I did listBox1.Items.Add("Hello World") from the scan button click method. Im sort of stuck here. Ive just started learning C# and if anyone could help me that would be greatly appreciated.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int PanelWidth;
    bool PanelCalShow;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PanelWidth = PanelCal.Width;
        PanelCalShow = false;           
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PanelCalShow)
        {
            PanelCal.Width = PanelCal.Width + 10;

            if (PanelCal.Width >= PanelWidth)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                PanelCalShow = false;
                this.Refresh();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (PanelCalShow != true)
            {
                PanelCal.Width = PanelCal.Width - 10;

                if (PanelCal.Width <= 0)
                {
                    timer1.Stop();
                    PanelCalShow = true;
                    this.Refresh();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Bluetooth connection
    private void BtnScan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var instance = new BtCom();
        instance.Scan();   
    }        

    public void LbClientUpdate(List<string> DiscoveredDevices)
    {                        
        listBox1.DataSource = DiscoveredDevices;            
    }        
}
```

and the bluetooth connection class

```
public class BtCom
{
    public List<string> DiscoveredDevices = new List<string>();
    Guid mUUID = new Guid("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    public void Scan()
    {            
        Thread bluetoothScanThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Scanning));
        bluetoothScanThread.Start();
    }

    BluetoothDeviceInfo[] devices;

    public void Scanning()
    {            
        var form1 = new Form1();

        BluetoothClient client = new BluetoothClient();
        devices = client.DiscoverDevicesInRange();

        foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo d in devices)
        {
            DiscoveredDevices.Add(d.DeviceName);
        }           
      form1.LbClientUpdate(DiscoveredDevices);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a function `LbClientUpdate` to set the DataSource of the ListBox, but it's not called from anywhere.

Comment: The reason you aren't seeing any update on your original form is that you are creating a new instance of the `Form1` class inside of your BtCom class instead of using the original instance.

Comment: Hi, sorry. I was deleting comments and must have deleted that as well. I had a messagebox with "hello world" after the listBox1.DataSource and that pops up like it should but nothing in the listbox. Could it be that because the method is called from a different thread it is executedin that thread as well, and as i understand, listbox should be edited from within its original thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you aren't seeing any update on your original form is that you are creating a new instance of the `Form1` class inside of your `BtCom` class instead of using the original instance.

One way you could fix this would be to pass the original instance of the form to your BtClass through a parameter to the `Scan` method, and then pass it along to your `Scanning` method. This way you will be calling methods on the same instance of the form that's running.

The problem with that is you will be blocking your UI while waiting for the thread to finish (assuming you call `bluetoothScanThread.Join()` to wait for the thread results).

A slightly different solution would be to use `Tasks`, with `async` methods that `await` results.

To do this, you would have your `scan` method return a `Task<List<string>>` (which is a `Task` that returns a `List<string>` representing the devices).

Then in `form1` you would create an `async` method (called `GetDatasource` below) that creates an instance of your `BtCom` class, `awaits` the `scan` method, and returns the `Task<List<string>>`.

Finally, you would also make the `Click` method `async` and have it assign await the `GetDatasource` method and assign the Datasource when it returns.

By doing it this way, you isolate the `BtCon` class from having to know any details about the `Form1` class, which is a good habit to get into because you end up creating more reusable and independent code.

Here's an example of all those words in code:

Make the `scan` method return a `Task<List<string>>` that can be used for the datasource (and have `Scanning` return a `List<string>`). Notice that the list is now private to the scanning method. It's a good practice to limit the scope of variables to only the level they are needed.:

```
public class BtCom
{
    Guid mUUID = new Guid("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    public Task<List<string>> Scan()
    {
        var bluetoothScanTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(Scanning);
        bluetoothScanTask.Wait();
        return bluetoothScanTask;
    }

    private List<string> Scanning()
    {
        BluetoothClient client = new BluetoothClient();
        devices = client.DiscoverDevicesInRange();

        List<string> discoveredDevices = new List<string>();

        foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo d in devices)
        {
            discoveredDevices.Add(d.DeviceName);
        }

        return discoveredDevices;
    }
}
```

Then, write an `async` method that will get the datasource by creating a new instance of this class, and `await` for the method to return. Also, make the `Click` method async so it can `await` the datasource method:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Other form code omitted...

    private async void BtnScan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.DataSource = await Task.Run(GetDatasource);
    }

    private async Task<List<string>> GetDatasource()
    {
        var btCom = new BtCom();
        List<string> results = await btCom.Scan();
        return results;
    }
```

Now your users can click the button and the form will continue to respond while the scanning takes place, and your listbox will populate when the scan method finishes.

For more on `async` and `await`, check your favorite search engine (like this page on [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async), for example).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Ill try everything out when I get home from work tonight. As I said Ive just started with C# and more or less with writing code all together so I really appreciate your help.